# SCHEME: how to input html and output it as html source?

Tags: html, input, scheme

I am trying to write a simple web app in scheme and I am using Drscheme for the job. I am wondering if there is a way to input html code into a form which then outputs it in html format (into source)? Is there a library that does the job? Everytime I input something it turns out as a string, I need it to be read as html. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. You wan to input HTML source and output it as pretty printed HTML?

Comment: I want to input html and append it to the source as HTML. For example, when I am trying to embed a video by submitting it, it returns the object as text. I would like it to be added as html code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HTML template files, then look at the [templates](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/web-server/templates.html) in the [web server manual](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/web-server/).  Also, in case you're not familiar with the web server, then see the [web server guide](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/continue/) for a good introduction.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to go from html string to scheme html code. For example, 

"<html><head><title>My Blog</title></head><body><h1>under construction</h1></body></html>" 

to:

'(html
     (head (title "My Blog"))
     (body (h1 "Under construction"))))

Comment: Start with a "(" and then for every opening HTML tag "<" insert a "(" and a closing ")" for every HTML closing tag "</". The text remains same of course. You can take a look at the HTML parsing library: http://docs.plt-scheme.org/html/index.html

Comment: in that case it would be: "(html)(head)(title)My Blog(title)(head)(body)(h1)under construction(h1)(body)(html) ?

Comment: Note that I told for every closing "</ and not ">". I think that should work. Also note that you will have to "look ahead" of "<" and see the next character. If it is "/" then replace the two chars by a ")", else replace it by a "(".

Comment: Well, your question is not really too defined.  If you mean how you can start with Scheme code *instead* of HTML code, and have it in a form that outputs HTML, then there are several frameworks that allow you to do that.

If you're talking about starting from actual HTML, and parsing it into Scheme structures and then generate HTML from that, then that's possible too (there are several HTML parsers in PLT and in libraries), but I don't see the point there, since you'd end up with HTML that is equivalent to what you started with...